Reflecting image using ReflectionTransform
My goal is to get an reflection of Triangle as below in a mirror through the point p, normal to the vector v using ReflectionTransform[v,p]. My question about usage of ReflectionTransform is how to set v and p to get reflection with respect to the horizontal axis?(※I have tried the v and p as {0,1} and {0,0}, but the image was not as expected.)
tri=Triangle[{{0,0},{1,0},{0,1}}];
img=Rasterize@Graphics[{White,EdgeForm[Thick],tri},PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2}},ImageSize->50]  (*image of a tringle*)

ImageTransformation[img,ReflectionTransform[{0, 1},{0,0}]]  (*How to get refection with respect to horizentol line passing {0,0}?*)


You can also use the DataRange option:
tri = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
img = Rasterize@Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Thick], tri},PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> 50];
imgR = ImageTransformation[img, ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}, {0, 0}],DataRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}/2}];
Column[{img, imgR}]



Thank you for your answer. As you mentioned, Option DataRange was the key. DataRange ->{ {-2,2},{-2,2} } also showed expected result

A simple solution is to use the PlotRange option:
ImageTransformation[img, ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}, {0, 0}], PlotRange -> All]


But I don't know how ImageTransformation sets the coordinate system for an image, so I don't know how general this solution would be.

This seems to be a peculiar behavior of ImageTransfrom. The original frame seems to be preserved and the transformed part, that is outside the original frame, is truncated. In addition, the part of the original frame that is not covered by the transformed picture is drawn black.
Consider a slightly turned triangle:
img = Image[Graphics[{Blue, Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]}]];
ImageTransformation[img, RotationTransform[5 °]]


In your example, the reflected image is outside the original frame and a black rectangle is shown.
